# How many concurrent await

Tags: c#, websocket, async-await

Taken form Paul Batum's example (https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples/blob/master/HttpListenerWebSocketEcho/Server/Server.cs) with all try/catches removed for the sake of lisiblity :

```
private async void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{
    WebSocketContext webSocketContext = await listenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
    WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;                                           

    byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];

    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveResult.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, receiveResult.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

If I understand well, each time a new client connects, a new "instance of" await `webSocket.ReceiveAsync()` is set.

I'm wondering how many clients this method could handle ; in other words, how many await may be "pending" ?

Comment: That depends primarily on your available memory.

Comment: @SLaks Nice ! So there's no such kind of advice like "do not launch more threads than you have cores...". In other words, it's not bad practice to have maybe hundreds or thousands of awaits, providing you have the memory.

Comment: No; these are not threads.  That's one of the primary advantages of asynchrony.

Comment: Yeah I know they're not threads but they may have had their own "philosophical" limitations... Thanks !

Comment: This article by Stephen Cleary might help: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html